# ASP.Net Core with nginx set host header not working

Tags: asp.net, nginx, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to host my ASP.Net core app using Nginx.

My **nginx.conf** like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;                
    }
}
```

I added this code to **Configure** method to use forwarded headers

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
    ForwardLimit = null,
    RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
});
```

I navigate to **mydomain.com** from browser and it works until I click the Loggin with google button. It redirect to http://**localhost:5000**/signin-google instead of http://**mydomain.com**/signin-google.

How do I get it redirect to http://**mydomain.com**/signin-google ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe proxy_redirect directive could help.

According to:
[NGinX Documentation for proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)

proxy_redirect: "Sets the text that should be changed in the “Location” and “Refresh” header fields of a proxied server response."

So:

```
proxy_redirect http://localhost:5000/ http://example.com/
```

May be the solution to your problem.

You may even be able to use a variable to make support easier?

```
proxy_redirect http://localhost:5000/ http://$host:$server_port
```

Further reading:
[Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-nginx)